# Using Fiddler to generate POST request with body

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, fiddler

I have a node.js service and it accepts POST requests. I am trying to use Fiddler to generate the post request. However, when I print the request body in my service, I get an empty object with no data in it. I set the request body in Fiddler to something such as `{key:value}`. When printing `request.body` in the node.js service I get an empty object `{}`.

The request header:

```
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:3000
Content-Length: 10
```

The body:

```
{ key:ky }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: if that's the body, it's not valid json, valid json is `{"key": "value"}`, otherwise please provide more code.

Comment: for example if I want to pass user object how do I do that ? Like this {User: "UserName"} ?

Answer (score 6):

In the header: `Content-Type: application/json`
In the body: `{"key": "value"}`